# Recreating Access report in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

```
IIf(IsNull([dbo_TASK]![restart_date]),[dbo_TASK]![target_start_date],[dbo_TASK]![restart_date]),[dbo_TASK]![act_start_date]) AS [Estimated Start Date]

IIf(IsNull([dbo_TASK]![act_end_date]),IIf(IsNull([dbo_TASK]![reend_date]),[dbo_TASK]![target_end_date],[dbo_TASK]![reend_date]),[dbo_TASK]![act_end_date]) AS [Estimated Finish Date]
```

I have above 2 fields in MS Access and trying to re-create it is SQL.

I tried using Case statement, but not getting correct results..
Please help

Comment: `iif(isnull(x), y, x)` is equivalent to `coalesce(x, y)`

Comment: coalesce(dbo.TASK.act_start_date, (coalesce(dbo.TASK.restart_date,dbo.TASK.target_start_date)) AS Test not working

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE looks at each field in order, it will return the first value that does not evaluate to NULL. You can list as many fields as you need to return a non-null value.

The first field would be:

```
COALESCE([dbo_Task].[restart_date],[dbo].[target_start_date])
```

The second would be :

```
COALESCE([dbo_TASK].[act_end_date],[dbo_TASK].[reend_date],[dbo_TASK].[target_end_date])
```

Comment: check the table and field names, make sure everything is spelt correctly.